# Show div with the same data-attribute as select option attribute

Tags: jquery, html, show

I would like to show divs that are set to display none in css depending on multiple if statements.
For this I want to use data-attributes and get that data value to match the data value of the hidden div.

the options:

```
<select class="selectOptions" id="selectOptions1">
    <option data-name="man">
        man1
    </option>
    <option data-name="woman">
        woman
    </option>
    <option data-name="child">
        child
    </option>   
</select>

<select class="selectOptions" id="selectOptions2">
    <option data-age="30">
        man1
    </option>
    <option data-age="25">
        woman
    </option>
    <option data-age="10">
        child
    </option>   
</select>
```

hidden divs:

```
<div class="dataTest" data-age="25" data-name="man">Hey Man</div>
<div class="dataTest" data-age="20" data-name="woman">Hello Woman</div>
<div class="dataTest" data-age="10" data-name="child">Hi Child</div>
```

and the js:

```
$('.selectOptions').on('change', function() {

  var ageValue = $('#selectOptions2 option:selected').data('age');
  var nameValue = $('#selectOptions1 option:selected').data('name');
 // alert(nameValue + ' ' + ageValue);

  $('.dataTest').filter(function() {
    return this.dataset.name === nameValue || this.dataset.age === ageValue
  }).css("display", "block").siblings(".dataTest").css("display", "none");
});
```

The values of the data attributes on change are found correctly as the alert is showing them, but then I can not use this variables in my conditions.
Any help is most welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try utilizing `.filter()` to select `.dataTest` element, `siblings()` to hide previously selected `.dataTest` siblings

```js
$('.selectOptions').on('change', function() {

      var ageValue = $(':selected', this).data('age');
      var nameValue = $(':selected', this).data('name');
      var filtered = ageValue || nameValue;
      alert(filtered);

      $('.dataTest').filter(function() {
        var name = this.dataset.name, age = this.dataset.age;
        return name == filtered || age == filtered 
      }).css("display", "block").siblings(".dataTest").css("display", "none");
    });
```

```css
.dataTest {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectOptions" id="selectOptions1">
    <option data-name="man">
        man1
    </option>
    <option data-name="woman">
        woman
    </option>
    <option data-name="child">
        child
    </option>   
</select>

<select class="selectOptions" id="selectOptions2">
    <option data-age="30">
        man1
    </option>
    <option data-age="25">
        woman
    </option>
    <option data-age="10">
        child
    </option>   
</select>
<div class="dataTest" data-age="25" data-name="man">Hey Man</div>
<div class="dataTest" data-age="20" data-name="woman">Hello Woman</div>
<div class="dataTest" data-age="10" data-name="child">Hi Child</div>
```

Comment: I probably explained the question wrong, there will be multiple select fields, thats why the or in the if condition. Will modify question. Thanks

Comment: @user2666378 More `select` elements than appear at `html` at Question ?

Comment: yes I updated the question as I thought it was of no importance having a shorter html example with multiple attributes on one option.

Comment: @user2666378 See updated post. Note, at `#selectedOptions2` "woman" age is set currently at "25" within `html`, which corresponds to `data-age` of `data-name="man"`  "Hey Man" at `.dataTest` ; not certain if this is expected result ? Approach filters `data-*` of selected option at `filtered` , before reaching `.filter()`

Comment: Exactly what I was going for. Thanks a million for your great solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the clicked handler you can use:

```
 $('.dataTest').hide();
 $("div[data-name="+$(this).find(':selected').attr('data-name')+"]").show();
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zxnbp2dL/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter()

```
$('.dataTest').hide().filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('name') === nameValue || $(this).data('age') === ageValue
}).show();
```

In your code `$(this)` inside `if()` refers select dropdown. So it won't work.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6xr6kj1k/)**

Also, if you are comparing the values using equality operator, the values should be same in select drowdown and the hidden divs.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code doesn't work because `$('.dataTest').data("name") == nameValue)` is going to compare the name value for the first item in the `$('.dataTest')` collection. This is typical for jQuery functions that return strings.

What you want is an attribute selector:

```
$(".dataTest[data-name=" + nameValue + "]").css("display", "block");
$(".dataTest[data-age=" + ageValue + "]").css("display", "block");
```